# Determining if a relation is reflexive, symmetric, or transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, relations, binary

Let $A = \{0,1,2,3\}$

Define a relation $T$ on $A$ as follows:

$T = \{(0,1),(2,3)\}$

Is $T$ reflexive? symmetric? transitive?

Comment: You've already received two votes to close the question, and sadly neither of these voters put in the effort to tell you how to improve your question before it gets closed.  You should update the question with your thoughts on the problem as soon as possible to avoid closure.  Also, this will help the community determine the best way to help you.  For example, do you know what reflexive, symmetric, and transitive mean?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange, Mark! On this site, we like to see some input from the questioner about the problems they are given. We are not a homework answering service. This isn't to say you *can't* ask homework questions here, but we like there to be some good faith on your part to assure that you've at least thought about this to some degree so we aren't just giving away free answers. What are your thoughts about this question? Do you know what it means for a relation to be transitive, symmetric or reflexive? What about these is giving you difficulty on this particular problem?

Answer (score 1):

To be Reflexive  you should have  (0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3)

To be symmetric  if you have     (0,1), then you should have (1,0)

To be transitive if you have  (1,2) (2,4), then you should have (1,4)

To answer your question
 NO for Symmetric and Reflexive 
 Yes for transitive because no counter example

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the definitions of reflexive, symmetric and transitive relations?

> A [reflexive relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation) is a binary relation on a set for which every element is related to itself.

As you can clearly see $(0,0),(1,1)$ etc. are not contained in your relation, so it is not reflexive.

> A relation is [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) if $aRb \implies bRa$.

Once again, $(0,1)$ is there in your relation but $(1,0)$ isn't. So it is not symmetric.

> Relation is [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) if $(aRb \wedge bRc) \implies aRc$.

There is no counter-example to this in your relation, so it is transitive.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the definitions and I thank you for taking your time to explain them again to me. Why is it transitive? How does it become a transitive relation simply because it lacks the second part?

Comment: It only fails to be transitive if the above condition is violated.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the simple and concise explanation!

Answer (score 0):

A relation is reflexive $\iff$ $\forall_{\alpha}(\alpha \in A)$$(\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle \in T)$. This is clearly not the case for T.

A relation is symmetric $\iff$ $\forall_{\alpha, \beta}(\alpha \in A)([\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\in T] \rightarrow [\langle\beta,\alpha\rangle \in T])$. This isn't the case for T either.

A relation is transitive $\iff$ $\forall_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}([\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle \in T \land \langle\beta,\gamma\rangle \in T] \rightarrow [\langle\alpha,\gamma\rangle \in T])$. Yes, this statement is vacuously true, I believe.